# How can I avoid creating a new observer chain for every getFlowable() call in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got a following class:

```
public class Service {

    private Observable<Long> obs = Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    private Single<Foo> sendFooRequest() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> sendHttpRequest());
    }

    public Flowable<Foo> getFlowable() {
        return obs
                .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .doOnNext(tick -> log.info("tick: {}", tick))
                .flatMapSingle(tick -> sendFooRequest())
                .distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}
```

It looks like each time I call `getFlowable()`, a new observer chain is created. The `Observable.interval()` operator uses the `Schedulers.computation()` executor to get a new thread to run on.

The issue is that I don't really want to call `sendFooRequest()` for each observer chain separately, I want to share the data (the response of `sendFooRequest()`) instead, how can I do it?

**Update**: I came up with the following solution, does it make sense?

```
public class Service {

    private Observable<Long> obs = Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    private BehaviorSubject<Long> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    FooPublisher() {
        obs.subscribe(subject);
    }

    private Single<Foo> sendFooRequest() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> sendHttpRequest());
    }

    public Flowable<Foo> getFlowable() {
        return subject
                .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .doOnNext(tick -> log.info("tick: {}", tick))
                .flatMapSingle(tick -> sendFooRequest())
                .distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Behaviour you need is called multicasting, and there are plenty of ways you can achieve it. You can do it with subject, but usually the way to go is `ConnectableObservable` via `publish` method as @Gustavo already described. Then depending on a context you can connect/refcount/autconnect/etc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for an operator send the same event to multiple subscriptions.

You should use the [publish](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html) operator in order to achieve that.

```
    public Flowable<Foo> getFlowable() {
        return subject
                .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .doOnNext(tick -> log.info("tick: {}", tick))
                .flatMapSingle(tick -> sendFooRequest())
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .publish()
                .autoConnect();
    }
```

The `autoConnect` operator is to set up the Flowable to start emitting when the first Subscriber subscribes.